# Revoke access from remote IP

Tags: mysql

This issue came up at work today and I have not been able to resolve it.
MySQL server 5.1.67

As mysql root user I have created a DB, user and granted all privileges from a remote IP

mysql> grant all privileges on `test`.* to 'jane'@'56.44.3.24' identified by 'password' ;

mysql> flush privileges ;

Jane is now coming in from a different IP 33.2.67.3 so I need to remove access from her old IP and allow access from her new IP. In tests I have tried the following but jane can still access from her old IP, scenario recreated on a couple of VM's using private IP's.

mysql> revoke all privileges on `test`.* to 'jane'@'56.44.3.24' identified by 'password' ;

Is this the correct syntax? What am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Kevin

Answer (score 4):

Check out the MySQL reference for REVOKE: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/revoke.html. You want something along the lines of:

```
REVOKE ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* FROM 'jane'@'56.44.3.24';
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but that does not stop the user from connecting. This does however: mysql> drop user 'jane'@'33.2.67.3' ; The user is only dropped from accessing from that IP. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

As per [kevin-mcnally](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2246390/kevin-mcnally)'s comment, I also had to do a

```
mysql> DROP USER jane@'56.44.3.24';
```

in order for it to be removed from `mysql.user` list, and to make it work for me.